# load stored procedure from sql file

Tags: mysql, go

I have a mysql test.sql file that contains stored procedure.
to load this sql file after connecting to database in go server, I used Exec command. But I haven't got the result I wanted. I take error code

> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corr...

How can I load stored procedure from a sql file after connecting the database in go.

// go code section :

```
sqlProc, err := ioutil.ReadFile("E:/Qlass/goserv/src/cevir/test.sql")
// handle error

_, err = MAPP.DB.Db.Exec(string(sqlProc[:]))
// handle error
```

// content of test.sql

```
drop procedure if exists Test;
delimiter ;;
create procedure Test()
begin
    truncate table _prlog;
end ;;
delimiter ;
```

problem is caused by the delimeter command. I removed those lines. Problem is solved. The corrected sql file.

```
drop procedure if exists Test;
create procedure Test()
begin
    truncate table _prlog;
end ;
```

Comment: "But I haven't got the result I wanted" - meaning what? What result did you want, what result did you get, what specifically is the issue you're having?

Comment: Post the error that you are getting if any.

Comment: I have corrected the question. I hope it's more descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect something more like this:

```
DB, err = sql.Open("mysql", MAPP.CF.Mysql)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(`E:/Qlass/goserv/src/modul/modul_sp.sql`)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
sqlProc := string(data)
_, err := DB.Exec(sqlProc)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have used your advise. But I have taken the same error code at Db.Exec line. The error code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corr...  I've minimized the amount of code in test stored procedure as much as possible to reduce the chance of error due to different sql command. The test.sql that I used is in question part.

Comment: peterSO, I have noticed the change you made to the variable later. In the meantime, I've fixed your code. I wanted to make it back to its original form, this time it was blocked by the rule of 6 char change. Sorry. and thanks again.

Comment: problem is caused by the delimeter command. I removed those lines. Problem is solved.